# Good pratice about concatenation in c ++ : Using functions or stringstream?

Tags: c++, string, concatenation, stringstream

I am learning C++ recently and coming in language like python which allows concatenation quite easily, I quickly wanted to concatenate different variables with a function, in order to avoid using strings or stringstream.

So I managed to create this function: (C++17)

```
#include <sstream>

template<typename... Types>
std::string concatenate(Types&&... args)
{
    std::stringstream s{};
    ((s << args), ...);
    return s.str();
}
```

My question is: Is it a good practice to use a function like this? Or should I get used to using strings variables which cannot concatenate only two values at the same time or should I use stringstream?

Comment: Why you cant use simple std::string?   auto s = s1 +s2+s3+"xyz"; should work

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why do you want to concatenate string representation of different types? Remember this is very costly - many heap allocations...

Comment: what does it mean to "concatenate different variables" when it isnt strings? And why do you want to avoid strings?

Comment: If you want something like python's `str.format` or %-interpolation, take a look at the [fmt](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) library.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to concatenate.   If you're just concatenating strings to strings, or characters and strings, then `std::string` provides the capability without need for steams.   If you're appending basic numerical types (`int`, `float`, etc) then - since C++11 - there is `std::to_string` which produces a string given a value.   If you're looking to concatenate user-defined types, then you need to specify an approach to concatenate them to strings.

Comment: The goal was to be able to use the call by doing : ```concatenate ("something ", "another : ", 45.3)``` And that the function returns : ```"something another : 45.3"```

Comment: I just inquired about allocations (heap, stack and static), I think I understand the additional cost that could result from a function as I wrote.

Comment: What this `"something another : 45.3"` will be used for? IF it will be just printed to stream consider to returns printable object that wraps these numbers 45 and 3.